# need to know about performance mysql vs Couchbase

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have three table in mysql 
user(1K) 
Campaign(6K)
CamapaignDailyUSes(70K)

If I get data of all user by

```
Select User.column1,User.column2,Campaign.column1 ,Campaign.column2 ,
DailyUSes.* from User Join Campaign join CamapaignDailyUSes
```

it will give result in few secounds may be.

But in **Couchbase**  N1ql it will take more then **1 minute**

what should Do fot it ?? even create some proper index.

How can i structure my Couchbase data ??

Comment: 1. are you using the MOI (Memory Optimized Indexes) or the regular GSI (Global Secondary indexes)?
2. What kind of indexes do you have in Couchbase?
3. Maybe prepared indexes can also help here.

Comment: GSI index. How can I use MOI index ?

Comment: When you install 4.5 or above, choose the "Memory Optimized Index" option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you post (or mail to prasad.varakur@couchbase.com) the sample docs. Did you explore restructuring/embedding to avoid some JOINS. What is the exact N1QL query? Couches4.5 onwards has two kinds of joins for better performance (leveraging indexes better), and allowing more flexibility in JOINs.

See https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/from.html#story-h2-3 for more info on lookup & index joins.

And, what are the sizes you specify.. size of document or number of documents??
If 70K is size of document, and you are fetching all of it, then what is the expected result size (based on selectivities).
If you have too big results, then you may want to use parameters (in 4.5.1) such as pretty=false, to minimize the n/w overhead.

-Prasad